# GCS limit bucket access to an existing service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Usually there is `Compute Engine default service account` that is created automatically by GCP, this account is used for example by VM agents to access different resources across GCP and by default has `role/editor` permissions.
Suppose I want to create GCS bucket that can only be accessed by this default service account and no one else. I've looked into ACLs and tried to add an ACL to the bucket with this default service account email but it didn't really work.
I realized that I can still access bucket and objects in this bucket from other accounts that have for example `storage bucket read` and `storage object read` permissions and I'm not sure what I did wrong (maybe some default ACLs are present?).

My questions are:

- Is it possible to limit access to just that default account? In that case who will not be able to access it?
- What would be the best way to do it? (would appreciate a lot an example using Storage API)
- There are still roles such as `role/StorageAdmin`, and actually no matter what ACLs will be put on the bucket I could still access it if I had this role (or higher role such as owner) right?

Thanks!

Comment: If an IAM identity has a role granting access to Cloud Storage, your only solution is to remove those permissions from each identity.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm trying to understand the relation between IAM and ACLs, if ACL is present on a bucket for a certain user, and some other user has some Storage Viewer role, he can still view bucket contents? What's the point of ACL then? IAM overrides ACL?

Comment: ACLs are legacy and existed before IAM. Either one grants permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you not to use ACL (and Google also). It's better to switch the bucket in uniform IAM policy.

There are 2 bad side of ACL:

- New created files aren't ACL and you need to set it everytime that you create a ne file
- It's difficult to know who has and who hasn't access with ACL. IAM service is better for auditing.

When you switch to Uniform IAM access, Owner, Viewer, and Editor role no longer have access to buckets (the role/storage.admin isn't included in this primitive role). It could solve in one click all the unwanted access. Else, as John said, remove all the IAM permission on the bucket and the project that have access to the bucket except your service account.

Comment: Not sure I understood your answer. Suppose I use Uniform IAM access on a bucket, that means that everyone who has for example storage.bucket.get and storage.object.get permissions can view my bucket with its objects? So if I want only one service account to access my bucket, I need to remove storage access in general from all other service accounts?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you let your house open, anyone can enter!

Comment: You are right, just a small remark, there are bucket-level and project-level IAM roles. So if I would restrict a certain service account to a bucket I would grant it bucket-level roles.

Comment: You have 4 levels of granularity for the role and permission: Organisation, Folder, Project and resource. Lower you are in this hierarchy finer is the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can control access to buckets and objects using [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) and [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl).

For example grant the service account WRITE (R: READ,W: WRITE,O: OWNER) access to the bucket using ACLs:

```
gsutil acl ch -u service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://my-bucket
```

To remove access of service account from the bucket:

```
   gsutil acl ch -d service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com gs://my-bucket
```

**If There are roles such as role/StorageAdmin in the IAM identities (project level), they will have access to all the GCS resources of the project. You might have to change the permission to avoid them having access.**

Comment: Hi, thanks you for you answer! But suppose someone has a simpler role, such as  Storage Object Viewer role, will ACL take effect in such case? I mean will account with such role be denied access because there is ACL on a bucket?